# Twitter data extraction by user using Twitter API

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, tweepy, analysis, tweets

How can i get user tweets using tweepy , but with user name not screen name, i have a list for company employees and i want to get their tweets, is there any solution ?

````
   ``` config.read('config.ini')

    api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
    api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']

    access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
    access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']

    # authentication
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #users = df['Name'].tolist()

    user_ids = []
    limit=300
    for user in users:
       tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user, count=200, 
      tweet_mode='extended').items(limit)

     #tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user, count=limit, 
    tweet_mode='extended')

    # create DataFrame
    columns = ['User', 'Tweet']
    data = []

    for tweet in tweets:
       data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text])

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
````

print(df1)```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with your code? Do you get an error? An unexpected result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.